# Question about Nearby Search Request from Google Places API

Tags: api, google-maps, google-places-api, google-nearby

[Image from table of pricing Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBw77.png)

About the image, i'm using the NearbySearch, and not found the SKU's corresponding

Result of request Nearby.

[Image of result of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82lgX.png)

I dont found the same fields in the PlaceDetails with Contact Data.. Atmosphere Data.. anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the API request you're making so that we can reproduce this from our side?